# Drupal upload file size error message

Tags: drupal, pdf, upload

Keep getting an error message re: file size: "The selected file could not be uploaded. The file is 53 KB which would exceed your disk quota of 2 MB." It says I am allowed 2MB per dowload, so if this file is 53KB, how can I be exceeding my quota?  I am stuck.

Comment: What module are you using for the uploads?  Is it the Drupal core, or a CCK module?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Drupal core "Upload" module... go to [your site]?q=admin/settings/uploads, there are settings for the file uploads.  You more than likely have a file upload limit on the "per user" settings, and you've used that up so far.  Bump that up really high, and you should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Quota is total usage. This means you have less than 53kb left until you reach 2mb.